# How can I move the cursor to the end of the text in RichEditBox?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, richeditbox

I'm building a Windows Phone 8.1/Windows 8.1 app (WinRT) and I'm using a RichEditBox control.
Every time I add text to it, the cursor goes to the beginning of the text and I can't find a way to move it to the end of the text.

I've build two methods to Set and Add text:

```
public static void SetText(this RichEditBox e, string text)
{
    e.Document.SetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextSetOptions.None, text); 
}

public static string GetText(this RichEditBox e)
{
   string value;
   e.Document.GetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextGetOptions.AdjustCrlf, out value); 
   return  value;
 }
```

And I'm using this code to add text to it:

```
StatusBox.SetText(StatusBox.GetText() +
                                  texttoadd);
```

Now, how can I move the cursor to the end of the text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By manipulating the `Selection` property in the `Document` property of the `RichEditBox`

```
var newPos = StatusBox.GetText().length-1;
StatusBox.Document.Selection.SetRange(newPos,newPos)
StatusBox.Focus(FocusState.Keyboard);
```

Comment: Is there really no way to do this without duplicating all the text in a buffer? That's insane.